# Javascript for...of loop over array of objects running one too many times

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have an array of objects that I'm iterating through and recording to Google Sheets, and it's working mostly fine, recording all of the objects in the array correctly. However my `catch` block is running at the end of the loop seemingly because it's trying to iterate over an object that doesn't exist, past the end of the array

**UPDATE** Even the debugger is seemingly messed up, showing a length of 6 but only 5 items in the array:

[image]

```js
const objArr = [
  {sender:'soandso',count:3,lastMessageDate:'2021-09-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject'},
  {sender:'suchandsuch',count:7,lastMessageDate:'2021-08-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 2'},
  {sender:'thisperson',count:2,lastMessageDate:'2021-03-02', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 3'},
  {sender:'thatperson',count:3,lastMessageDate:'2019-09-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 4'},
  {sender:'anotherone',count:4,lastMessageDate:'2016-02-14', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 5'},
  ];
  
const keys = Object.keys(objArr[0]); 
/* Updated thanks to comments, this is what I've had in my code, I didn't reproduce it correctly */

/* Note: Counting starts at 1 for rows and columns, rather than 0 */
  
  try {
    /* each object should be recorded to a new row of the sheet, starting at row 2, 
    because row 1 is a header row */
    let row = 2;
    for(let obj of objArr) {
      /* Each property within an object should be recorded starting at 
      the leftmost column and moving to the right. Reset after each object */
      let column = 1;
      for (let key of keys) {
        console.log(key);
        activeSheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(obj[key]); //activeSheet is a Google Sheet
        console.log(obj[key]);
        column++;
      }
      row++;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err.message} Unable to record sender information`);
  }
```

I end up with the following in the script logger:

```
...
12:00:38 PM Info    lastMessageDate
12:00:38 PM Info    2016-02-14
12:00:38 PM Info    lastMessageSubject
12:00:38 PM Info    Test Subject 5
12:00:38 PM Info    sender
12:00:38 PM Info    Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined Unable to record sender information
12:00:39 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

I don't understand how `for...of` could possibly loop more times than there are items in the array, I'm guessing maybe something to do with the `i` and `j` iterators? If someone could point out the (probably simple) mistake I made, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `for(let obj of objArr)` will give you each item one by one in `obj` and your for loop `for (let key of keys) ` will generate [0,1,2,3,4]. So for your each `obj` it will iterate again for `[0,1,2,3,4]` i.e for 5 times. We could solve it if you explain what you want to do with the array.

Comment: The error is not reporoducable with the code provided. I would reccomend logging out the obj before it throws the error. a nice lil `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: Are you doing `const keys = Object.keys(objArr);` or `Object.keys(objArr[0]);`? Your log output doesn't match your code.

Comment: `Object.keys(objArr)` - you trying to get keys, but from non-object here

Comment: Thanks for the criticism! I updated that `Object.keys` call to what's actually in my code and added some explanatory comments, and renamed the `i` and `j` variables to make it more clear what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always my own fault, I swear.

Earlier in the function, I was *trying* to assign the length of `objArr` + 1 to a variable, but accidentally incremented the length value itself (which I didn't even know was possible)

Wrong: `let rows = objArr.length++`

vs

Right `let rows = objArr.length + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function testBelow() {
  const objArr = [
    { sender: 'soandso', count: 3, lastMessageDate: '2021-09-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject' },
    { sender: 'suchandsuch', count: 7, lastMessageDate: '2021-08-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 2' },
    { sender: 'thisperson', count: 2, lastMessageDate: '2021-03-02', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 3' },
    { sender: 'thatperson', count: 3, lastMessageDate: '2019-09-27', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 4' },
    { sender: 'anotherone', count: 4, lastMessageDate: '2016-02-14', lastMessageSubject: 'Test Subject 5' },
  ];

  let oA = objArr.map( o => [o.sender,o.count,o.lastMessageDate, o.lastMessageSubject] );
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);

}
```

Active Sheet:

| soandso | 3 | 2021-09-27 | Test Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| suchandsuch | 7 | 2021-08-27 | Test Subject 2 |
| thisperson | 2 | 2021-03-02 | Test Subject 3 |
| thatperson | 3 | 2019-09-27 | Test Subject 4 |
| anotherone | 4 | 2016-02-14 | Test Subject 5 |

Comment: That doesn't look like a bad option, I'm just kind of married to `for` loops for no good reason. I'd also like to understand what's wrong with where I started that the loop is running too many times.

Comment: The I'd recommend diving into the debugger and figure it out.