# Under what circumstances would it be useful to change a javascript array's length, without actually adding a new element

Tags: javascript, arrays

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365854/javascript-for-of-loop-over-array-of-objects-running-one-too-many-times?noredirect=1#comment122604614_69365854), I figured out that my problem was because I had accidentally incremented the `Array.Prototype.length` property using `++`

What I'm wondering is why `length` isn't a read-only property of Arrays? I see that it isn't an oversight in the language's design, because [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) says specifically it can "***SET*** or return" the length of an array. I'm just wondering *why* I'm able to screw up in that particular way? What kind of use case would merit being able to change the length of an array without changing the number of elements it contains?

Comment: Setting it to a value lower than its current size will truncate the tail past that value, which I guess is useful. Not sure why would you want to set a higher value though

Answer (score 1):

I found [this interesting article](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-length/) from JavaScriptTutotorial.net that explains why you might use this.

#### Empty an array

If you set length to zero, the array will be empty:

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
fruits.length = 0;

console.log(fruits); // []
```

#### Remove elements

If you set the length property of an array to a value that is lower than the highest index, all the elements whose index is greater than or equal to the new length are removed.

The following example changes the length property of the fruits array to two, which removes the third element from the array:

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
fruits.length = 2;

console.log(fruits); // [ 'Apple', 'Orange' ]
```

#### Make array sparse

If you set the length property of an array to a value that is higher than the highest index, the array will be spare. For example:

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
fruits.length = 5;

console.log(fruits); // [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', <2 empty items> ]
```

Comment: I can see the use in decreasing the length to remove elements rather than using `.pop()`, or to empty it, but this doesn't explain how a "sparse" array could be useful?

Comment: Agreed. I think emptying and removing elements is somewhat useful, though I can't think of any non-contrived reason to make the array sparse. Contrived reason: Maybe you have a DOM list populated by the length of an array, and you want a minimum of X number of elements to appear. (Think: "List your favorites foods! Try to list at least 5" or something)